# Swift 3 WKWebView open link(url) in different View Controller's WKWebView

Tags: swift3, wkwebview

[image: I have ViewController1 with WKWebView need open a link inside ViewController2 WKWebView.]

I have tryed code below, but not sure how to pass request.url to WKWebView of second ViewController.

```
 func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    switch navigationType{
                case .linkClicked:
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySeque", sender:self)


                return false


            default:
                return true

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass URLRequest and WKWebViewConfiguretion from FirstWKWebViewController to SecondWKWebViewController

Refer below implementation

---

In FirstWKWebViewController keep global variables as

```
var firstURLRequest: URLRequest?
```

say your WKWebView is

```
firstWebView
```

Modify your code as

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

switch navigationType{

            case .linkClicked:

                 firstURLRequest = request //<---code add
                 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySeque", sender:self)
                 return false

            default:
                return true
        }
```

}

Create two variable in SecondWKWebViewController as

```
var secondURLRequest: URLRequest?
var secondWebConfiguration: WKWebViewConfiguration?
```

then in FirstWKWebViewController pass WebConfiguration and URLReqest before segue call

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let segueIdentifier = segue.identifier {

        switch segueIdentifier { 
        case "mySeque":

            if let secondWKWebVC = segue.destination as? SecondWKWebViewController {
                if nsurlreq != nil { secondWKWebVC.secondURLRequest = nsurlreq! as URLRequest }
                secondWKWebVC.secondWebConfiguration = firstWebView.configuration     
            } 
        default:
            return
        }
    }

}
```

Then in SecondWKWebViewController

```
guard let secondURLRequest = secondURLRequest else 
{ fatalError("No secondURLRequest") }

guard let secondWebConfiguration = secondWebConfiguration else 
{ fatalError("No webConfiguration") }

//WKWebView
seconWKWebView = WKWebView(frame: <yourValue>, configuration: secondWebConfiguration)
```